# How to reorder build queue waitlist for TFS Agent?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, agent, azure-pipelines-build-task

Is there any way to programatically reorder the build queue priority on TFS Agent

For example, at the moment I've 4 builds in the queue on Agent-1

```
build #1
build #2
build #3
build #4
```

Currently build #1 is running. Once it's finished, I want TFS Agent-1 to pick
build #3 in place of build #2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am afraid that this feature does not exist yet in Azure DevOps.

There is a popular [feature request](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/365507/ability-to-set-build-priority.html) regarding this, you can upvote there to get more attention from Microsoft:

[image]

Comment: Interesting that Azure DevOps ReST API seem to support setting priority: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/queue#queuepriority